# Ubuntu + PBS + Apache?  How can I show a list of running jobs as a website?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-10.04, pbs

Is there a plugin/package to display status information for a PBS queue?  I am currently running an apache webserver on the login-node of my PBS cluster.  I would like to display status info and have the ability to perform minimal queries without writing it from scratch (or modifying an age old python script, ala jobmonarch).  **Note, the accepted/bountied solution must work with Ubuntu.**

**Update:** In addition to ganglia as noted below, I also looked that the [Rocks Cluster Toolkit](http://www.rocksclusters.org), but I firmly want to stay with Ubuntu.  So I've updated the question to reflect that.

**Update 2:** I've also looked at [PBSWeb](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~pinchak/PBSWeb/) as well as [MyPBS](http://my-pbs.sourceforge.net/) neither one appears to suit my needs.  The first is too out-of-date with the current system and the second is more focused on cost estimation and project budgeting.  They're both nice, but I'm more interested in resource availability, job completion, and general status updates.  *So I'm probably just going to write my own from scratch -- starting Aug 15th.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ganglia?

I have no personal experience but few sysadmin I know are using it.

Following pages may help,

http://taos.groups.wuyasea.com/articles/how-to-setup-ganglia-to-monitor-server-stats/3

http://coe04.ucalgary.ca/rocks-documentation/2.3.2/monitoring-pbs.html

my two cents

Comment: I have now tried ganglia.  I used the add-on package jobmonarch.  I spent five hours on it last night and couldn't get it to work.  jobmonarch looks like it halted development 3 years ago.  Is there another add-on or package I should be supplementing ganglia with?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using nagios: http://www.nagios.org/  ?

Comment: The Torque plugin appears incapable of providing a list of running jobs.  I consider this a necessity.

Comment: Oh ok! I will let you know if I find any other options!