# I want to write an app to get a PBS cluster status updates, which platform would be easiest to learn?

Tags: mobile

**Direct Question:** I have a clear problem in mind -- I have a [PBS cluster running Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=289767) -- I know C/C++ very well.  I want to write a mobile application capable of querying the status of my cluster.  I will most likely have to learn another language to develop a mobile application.

Which platform should I choose: Android, iOS, Blackberry, or something else? What is the easiest platform to pick up?

Note: my contract is about up on my phone so I'm willing to switch to whichever platform is the easiest to learn.

**Background**: In about a month I'm going to start burning the candle at both ends to develop server side stuff - mostly written in Perl and/or PHP.  Let's assume I'll serve most of the data as HTML and RSS, but also allow authenticated queries to get job status, error reports, etc.

I have a hunch that Java is probably the best way to go, and I'm already comfortable with the eclipse IDE.  But I really don't know where to start in terms of a platform.  I tried to land an Android book or two from the local Borders before they closed, but I've been so busy I didn't get there before they were gone.

Any thoughts are welcome.

I'd happily relocate this question if it's more appropriate somewhere else?

Comment: couldn't this be done via the web browser on the phone, as there are existing web interfaces to PBS (for example: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~pinchak/PBSWeb/)?

Comment: I have never heard of that:  I offered a bounty on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962265) and no one mentioned it.  On the link provided, it notes *Last updated on July 8, 2003*, have you had any recent experience with it? -- Note I'd install it tonight and test it out, but I just lost two HDD on my queue manager (in Raid 5), so I'm stuck rebuilding it from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

Since you know c and c++, and if you own a mac and the $100 cost of getting the platform is not an issue, then I would go with objective-C and develop an Iphone app since it is very similar to C and C++ and should be very easy to pick up. If the things I mentioned are issue tho, then I would develop an android app, and Java is not that hard to learn either. Good Luck!

Comment: I don't own a mac.  Which makes developing for the iPhone look less attractive.  So I'm more tempted to go the Android route, but now with all of the lawsuits coming up -- I'm really unsure.

Comment: You mean the Oracle law suit? I really think that would be a problem.

Comment: I'm sure google is gonna do something about it. They'll probably just buy java from Oracle.